# How to display fields of a content part when we add a new instance of a content type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, orchardcms

I'm trying to create a custom module which includes a content type (Project) which contains a content-part (ProjectPart). Projects will be created by admin. And the goal is to show these created project on a specific page.

When I try to instantiate a new project on the admin menu, I only see one field (Description). Other fields are not shown.

I followed [the steps (starting from PersonPart.cs) in "Lombiq.TrainingDemo" project](https://github.com/Lombiq/Orchard-Training-Demo-Module/blob/orchard-core/StartLearningHere.md), and managed to create a custom module which includes a content type (Project), a content part (ProjectPart). Comments in the project claim that we can create an instant with all fields. But this is not true for my case.

Here is my code:

https://gist.github.com/vogucore/efb0096e349591c235103e4f3f9e60d1

[Here you can see what I exactly mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiaM9.png)

I expect to see & edit all of its field, but only "Description" field is shown up.

Could you please tell me whether I'm missing something, or the explanation in the project is not true?

Thanks in advance. Peace! (;

Comment: your code have not access to see in public. please insert your code as part of question.

Comment: Sorry. My fault. I made it public. So you can see it in gist now.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, i upvoted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are confusing properties of a content part with fields of a content part, which are two different concepts in Orchard.

Parts are regular C# objects that can have regular C# properties. Using such properties is the valid and mainstream way for developers to extend the CMS and build custom parts in Orchard.

Fields are smaller units of contents (typically a single string, or a number, or an image, etc.) that can be *dynamically* added to a part, trough code or through the admin's content type definition editors. They have the advantage that the administrator of the site can add, remove and modify them at runtime.

It's very understandable that you'd confuse them: they are both name/value thingies that you can attach to a part. In terms of actual usage, a good way to choose between the two is to ask the following question:

Is this a core property that is firmly attached to the part concept I'm building, or something that would be nice for administrators to attach to it if it makes sense to them?

For example, if I build a commerce product part, it would make sense that the SKU and price would be part properties. Now a product photo is different in that not all products may necessarily have a photo, some may have several, may be videos, who knows? It's just not an intrinsic property that makes a product a product. So make that a field (a media picker field to be specific).

To get back to your specific example, you should not be adding that field in your migration: it's basically creating something that looks like it's your `Description` property, but actually is a `Description` field, in addition to your property of the same name.

The reason why your part properties don't appear on your editor is that you aren't done with your part. You still need to [build a driver](https://github.com/Lombiq/Orchard-Training-Demo-Module/blob/orchard-core/Drivers/PersonPartDisplayDriver.cs), and [views](https://github.com/Lombiq/Orchard-Training-Demo-Module/tree/orchard-core/Views) for it (the field didn't need that because they were already built by whoever built that field).

As a side note, I think the good Lombiq folks made a lousy choice by giving that `Biography` property the `TextField` type. It's very confusing, and should really be a string, in my opinion, and so should your `Description` property.

Comment: Actually what I was expecting from OrchardCore was to create html elements for well-known types (string, int, etc..) automatically. And I thought, I need to use specific fields or settings when I want to specify a well-known type (i.e. I want string property to be made of only characters).

Thank you very much for this excellent answer. I appreciate.

Comment: It does, if you use fields, and maybe that's what you want to use if you want to manage contents at a relatively low level. 

Orchard however really shines when using parts, which are a little better fit to content management, and are higher-level and have more functionality. I mean, you could handle blog posts as a title string, a body string, an author string, a date, etc., but it's way more useful to compose it from slightly higher level parts that are closer to actual usage, such as an actual title part, and actual markdown part, a metadata part, and maybe a picture part, comments, etc.

Comment: ... strings and integers and dates, etc. are fine if you're building a database, or creating a C# class, but a CMS can do better and have abstractions that are a better fit for the domain.